# Jenkins deploy WAR to Tomcat Raspberry Pi

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment

I am trying to get my application deployed automatically on my raspberry pi which is running a tomcat7 instance. I configured a new jenkins project, the building works flawless now the only issue remaining is the actual deployment.
The Tomcat server is running on port 5000 in case you are wondering.
When trying to deploy I get this exception from within jenkins:

```
[INFO] Deployment in  (id=,uniqueVersion=true)
Deploying the main artifact MyProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: Unsupported transport protocol 
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance(WagonTransporterFactory.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:110)
Caused: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: Cannot access  using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:115)
Caused: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access  using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
Caused: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access  with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:265)
Caused: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access  with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:420)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
Caused: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access  with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactRecord.deploy(MavenArtifactRecord.java:193)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenAggregatedArtifactRecord.deploy(MavenAggregatedArtifactRecord.java:95)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenAbstractArtifactRecord$1.perform(MavenAbstractArtifactRecord.java:235)
    at hudson.model.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:129)
```

But I do not understand what the issue is and how to fix it. Can anyone help me fix this? I am literally like 20 minutes into jenkins and do not know a whole lot. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iLo0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a *Maven* deployment of your artifact to a Maven repository, not deploying a WAR file to a Tomcat.

I would suggest copying the WAR file to the webapps directory inside a running Tomcat by hand instead.

Comment: There was an error in the mysql installation causing it to crash

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in jenkins where you can deploy into a container in configure

add the details of your tomcat 
[image]

To get a full detailed explanation I have answered it here
[Deploying web application in tomcat on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766402/deploying-web-application-in-tomcat-on-jenkins/49503731#49503731)

Hope it helps :)